# Ubuntu 18.04.3 second screen detected but black

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, external-monitor

I have Lenovo thnikpad T490 with Ubuntu 18.04.3.

When I connect the laptop to a docking station or directly with HDMI, it extends perfectly, but at home I have an old external Samsung monitor that has only DVI as input, so i use a HDMI-DVI adapter. When connecting this display, it is detected, but while the operating system behaves like it works, the screen is black. When connecting a Windows-powered laptop, the display works fine.

uname -a:

`Linux T490-ubuntu 5.0.0-36-generic #39~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 11:09:50 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

lshw -c display:

```
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:147 memory:c7000000-c7ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

xrandr --listmonitors

```
Monitors: 2
 0: +*eDP-1 1920/309x1080/173+0+0  eDP-1
 1: +HDMI-2 1920/531x1080/299+0+0  HDMI-2
```

I already tried some suggested solutions:

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode 1920x1080 --output HDMI-2 --mode 1920x1080 --same-as eDP-1
```

and I added `amdgpu.dc=0` to grub, but nothing works.

Comment: and if you run `xrandr --listmonitors` while connected to the Samsung monitor it shows you having more than 1 screen connected?

Comment: Yes it does, I will add this to the question